# BreezeJS not querying an CORS OData web api service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

I'm trying to use breezejs for querying an webapi odata service that is hosted in a separate application instance/domain.

I have set everything like described on the [official BreezeJS site](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata) and [this blog post](http://briannoyes.net/2013/02/16/ConsumingAnASPNETWebAPIODataServiceWithBreeze.aspx) the code is identical except the service address will be on another domain.

Here is the code example:

```
    var serverAddress = 'http://mydomain.com:49074/odata/';
    breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });

    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serverAddress);
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Technology').where("Id", ">", 3); //!!!not executed

    manager.executeQuery(query, function (data) {
        debugger;
        alert('tada');
    });
```

Such formed query isn't executed **but it should work**. And get such a response:

***Headers:***

> Request URL:http://mydomain.com:49074/odata/$metadata 
>   Request Method:GET 
>   Status Code:200 OK

***Response:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
  <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <Schema Namespace="Devup.Model" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
      <EntityType Name="Technology">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
      </EntityType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="WebAPIODataWithBreezeConsumer.Models" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
      <EntityContainer Name="Container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
        <EntitySet Name="Technology" EntityType="Devup.Model.Technology" />
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

However noticed that if I update the query to:

var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Technology?').where("Id", ">", 3);

OR

var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Technology/').where("Id", ">", 3);

then I hit the backend code (break point) it doesn't filter the result but hits the backend...

Does anyone know why such a strange behavior and how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Not sure quite what is happening but you might be able to simplify the problem by isolating the metadata query from the data query.  By default, Breeze attempts to resolve metadata for any query before attempting to execute the query itself.  The metadata resolution will only need to occur once per data service endpoint and will typically show up as two roundtrips on your first query.  This can make debugging the issue difficult.

The alternative is to force the metadata query to occur before your first data query by performing the metadata query explicitly via

```
// fetch the metadata
myEntityManager.fetchMetadata().then(function() {
   return myEntityManager.executeQuery(myQuery);

}).then(function(data) {
// fetch the data 
   var results = data.results;
});
```

With this setup,  you can determine if the metadata query is failing or the data query is failing.